# Azure Cosmos Table API Date Query doesn't return data

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage

I am using Cosmos DB, and I try to query data based on the PartitionKey and a Datetime field.
Using the Cosmos DB Data Explorer in the Azure Portal the query editor produces the following query:

```
PartitionKey eq 'myPartitionKey' and Timestamp ge datetime'2022-08-13T20:40:11.426Z'
```

This returns data as expected. However, if I try the same query using the C# Table API it seems something is off (or maybe I did an issue here):

```
        string queryDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-31).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string query = $"PartitionKey eq '{slug}' and Timestamp ge datetime'{queryDate}'";
        AsyncPageable<TableEntity> queryResultsMaxPerPage = tableClient.QueryAsync<TableEntity>(filter: query, maxPerPage: 500);

        await foreach (Page<TableEntity> page in queryResultsMaxPerPage.AsPages()) 
        {
             ...
        }
```

This doesn't return any Data unfortunately.
If I try this code with another query, it returns data as expected. For example if I use the following query, I am able to query data and get a response containing:

```
PartitionKey eq 'myPartitionKey'
```

Hope someone can help me

Comment: When you debug is query as expected?

Comment: Can you try using this instead? yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ

Comment: When I debug "query" is almost the same as in the Portal. (just a date difference by minutes, shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: Using yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ seems not to help